# Strange JavaScript assignment with logical or

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm building a JavaScript parser and got an error when testing it on jQuery on line 496:

```
isArray: Array.isArray || function( obj ) {
    return jQuery.type(obj) === "array";
},
```

I have reduced it down to this:

```
a = b || function() {}
```

Is this valid ECMA-262 or is it a feature that has been added since then?  Either way, how do I express it in terms of a parser?

My abstract syntax tree for an assignment expression is:

```
data Assignment
    = CondExpr        CondExpr
    | Assign          LeftExpr AssignOp Assignment 
    | AssignFuncDecl  FuncDecl
```

This doesn't support assignments in the above format.

I can explain my AST more if needed. Thanks for any help you can give!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look for "ecma bnf". Here's [one](http://tomcopeland.blogs.com/EcmaScript.html) of the links.

Comment: Ah, this is really handy.  I wish I'd had this when I started... I managed to track down my error.  Turns out I missed out FunctionExpression in MemberExpression.  Thanks.